# Вглубь или в глубь?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, части-речи

В текстах часто встречается разные написания "вглубь" и "в глубь", причем практически в одинаковых ситуациях. Как правильно сформулировать правило их выбора и объяснить  приведенные примеры?

(1)Зубатка не приветствует незваных гостей и забивается (в) глубь норы.

(2)И вот наш «одарённый» герой продолжил ползти (в)глубь норы.

(3)Вода заполнила все проходы и гроты,  (в)глубь земли ей путь прегражден.

(4)Я удаляюсь (в) глубь лесов под звонкий голос менестреля.

(5)Эта история уходит (в) глубь веков.

(6)И это путешествие (в) глубь земли и (в) глубь времен захватывает зрителей.

(7)Сумрак тихий, сумрак сонный, лейся (в) глубь моей души.

(8)Каменистые гряды уходят от берега (в) глубь озера.

Comment: Во всех примерах (1)...(8) — существительные с предлогом, раздельно.

---------------------------- 
*За двести лет развития содержание этой науки обогатилось вширь и вглубь.* Наречия, слитно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=661

В зависимости от понимания текста пишущий может выбрать и слитное, и раздельное написание в таких, например, случаях: погрузиться вглубь (в глубь)океана, зайти вглубь (в глубь) леса, гнездо наверху (на верху) дерева.

В школе предлагается писать раздельно существительные при наличии зависимых слов: в глубь реки, в глубь леса , в глубь истории, в глубь времен,  в глубь легенды, в глубь материи, в глубь души.

Слитное написание у предлога "вглубь", если его можно заменить предлогом "внутрь": вглубь кармана, вглубь норы. Однако это решение не является общепринятым, разные встречаются варианты.

Когда не совсем ясно, это производный предлог или предлог с существительным, я пользуюсь таким  приёмом: заменяю его на синоним, в частеречной принадлежности которого нет сомнений.

вглубь океана -- внутрь океана,вглубь леса -- внутрь леса,
наверху дерева --  на дереве

в глубь океана -- в пучину океана,в глубь леса -- в чащу леса,
на верху дерева -- на вершине дерева.

1)Зубатка не приветствует незваных гостей и забивается куда? вглубь норы.(внутрь)

(2)И вот наш «одарённый» герой продолжил ползти (куда? во что?)в (самую)глубь норы.

(3)Вода заполнила все проходы и гроты, вглубь(внутрь) земли ей путь прегражден.

(4)Я удаляюсь куда? во что? в(самую) глубь (чащу)лесов под звонкий голос менестреля.

(5)Эта история уходит (куда? во что?)в глубь веков. Но можно и внутрь веков.

(6)И это путешествие (куда?)вглубь земли и вглубь времен (внутрь)захватывает зрителей.

(7)Сумрак тихий, сумрак сонный, лейся (во что?)в глубь(глубину) моей души.

(8)Каменистые гряды уходят от берега (куда?) вглубь озера.

Но это тоже субъективно, я так подумала, а кто-то подумает по-другому.

Answer (score 3):

Между предлогом и существительным можно вставить слово. Например, в САМУЮ глубь норы. В наречии такого не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Благодарю всех, кто принял участие в дискуссии, и попробую тоже  ответить на заданный вопрос.

1. При наличии ЗАВИСИМОГО СЛОВА слово ГЛУБЬ пишется раздельно с предлогом «В» в большинстве случаев.
   Для справок: Согласно толковым словарям, значение существительного ГЛУБЬ совпадает с одним из значений существительного ГЛУБИНА – это место на дне глубокого водоема, то есть  глубь озера или реки.  По аналогии, глубью называют также место, ОТДАЛЕННОЕ ОТ КРАЯ ИЛИ НАЧАЛА – глубь леса, сада, а также – В ПЕРЕНОСНОМ ЗНАЧЕНИИ – глубь времен, глубь материи.
2. В то же время существует  наречный предлог ВГЛУБЬ со слитным написанием,  который  желательно использовать в том случае, если речь идет О НАПРАВЛЕНИИ, А НЕ О ПРЕДМЕТНОМ ЗНАЧЕНИИ существительного  ГЛУБЬ.
3. Различить эти два значения достаточно сложно, поэтому многие пользователи вообще не знают о существовании наречного предлога и используют только  раздельную форму написания. Возможно, именно так надо поступать при выполнении учебных заданий.
4. В то же время не надо удивляться, если в художественных текстах вы встретите предлог ВГЛУБЬ (чего-либо) со слитным написанием (обычно это авторский вариант).
5. Это решение тоже авторское:

(1)Зубатка не приветствует незваных гостей и забивается в глубь норы (в самую глубину норы).

(4)Я удаляюсь  в глубь лесов под звонкий голос менестреля (в глубину лесов)

(5)Эта история уходит в глубь веков (в глубину веков).

(7)Сумрак тихий, сумрак сонный, лейся  в глубь моей души (в глубину души)

(2)И вот наш «одарённый» герой продолжил ползти  ВГЛУБЬ НОРЫ (направление).

(3)Вода заполнила все проходы и гроты,  ВГЛУБЬ ЗЕМЛИ ей путь прегражден (направление)

(6)И это путешествие  ВГЛУБЬ ЗЕМЛИ и ВГЛУБЬ ВРЕМЕН захватывает зрителей (направление)

(8)Каменистые гряды уходят от берега  ВГЛУБЬ ОЗЕРА (направление)