# Вглубь или в глубь территории?

Tags: предлоги

*Уверенным шагом шёл в глубь территории Российской Федерации.*

Я так понимаю, в глубь раздельно, т. к. можно сказать: в глубь чего? Территории РФ.

Comment: Ответ можно найти здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/%D0%92%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8C

Comment: Здесь более конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Желательно выбрать раздельное написание: **...шёл в глубь территории.**

Глубь ― это не только морская глубина, но и удаленность от края территории, и  речь здесь идет **не о конкретном направлении, а именно о продвижении далеко от границ.**

**В Нацкорпусе** 16 примеров со раздельнымнаписанием и 3 пример со слитным:

(1) Наконец, движение австро-германских войск **в глубь территории**, опережаемое самыми фантастическими и угрожающими слухами, создавало психологическую обстановку, далеко не благоприятную для большевиков. [А. И. Деникин. Очерки русской смуты. Том II. Борьба генерала Корнилова (1922)]

(2)В присутствии наших кораблей авиация ЮАР, свободно проникавшая на сотни километров **в глубь территории** Анголы, старательно избегала побережья. [Кому не дает покоя слава «Ангольского Рембо» (2004) // «Солдат удачи», 2004.06.09]

(3)Покуда внутри страны длилась тяжкая тяжба за власть, ― незащищенные границы государства угрожающее передвигались **вглубь территории**. [Н. В. Устрялов. Под знаком революции (1927)]

Comment: Несмотря на это, в РАН написано, что можно и *в глубь океана*, и *вглубь океана* писать (в зависимости от того, что автор имеет в виду).

Comment: Да. здесь просматривается возможность авторского решения, а также. важно учитывать контекст. И ведь у меня не написано: правильно только так, а написано: желательно выбрать. А вот для варианта "из глуби" выбирать не приходится, там одна форма. Да еще о стилистике не мешает задуматься.

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что имеется зависимое слово, вряд ли можно ориентироваться на некое производное понятие "глубь территории": по отношению к территории "глубь" - явное просторечие, это совсем не то, что образное "морская глубь", которую можно было бы трактовать как существительное. Поэтому "**вглубь**" здесь выполняет функцию предлога направления, аналогичного таким как "**внутрь**", "**вокруг**" (территории) и им подобным. Раздельно было бы в случаях "в глубину", "в пределы", "в середину", "в обход" и т. п. - для "геометрических" понятий, которые существуют самостоятельно и сочетаются с "территорией".

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта допустимы. Наречие "вглубь" тоже существует.
Вопрос, таким образом, стилистический, то есть в том, насколько сочетается существительное глубь и наречие вглубь с понятием "Российская Федерация". 
И тут я бы предпочла именно наречие "вглубь", поскольку речь, судя по всему, идет о какой-то внутренней территории, а совсем не о том, что называют "глубинкой" и уж не о глубине точно.
А вглубь в значении "вовнутрь" вполне тут подходит.
Но это вопрос, повторюсь, стилистический,  потому во многом - субъективный. Раздельное написание ошибкой не будет.